# The geometric interpretation of Gorenstein local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, gorenstein

Many local rings have geometric interpretations. Cohen–Macaulay rings correspond to equi-dimensionality, and regular local rings correspond to non-singularity, but what is a geometric interpretation of Gorenstein local rings? I am not able to find one, so suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Cohen-Macaulay is much stronger than the equidimensionality which is just a topological property.

Comment: see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159536/geometric-interpretation-and-differences-of-gorenstein-rings-complete-intersect)